# Trying to set up Guardfile for web development, cannot add sub-directory check

Tags: regex, linux, guard

I am trying to set-up a guardfile for a simple web development project.

I want it to check the HTML files in the current dir, and the CSS files in the `./css/` directory.

I am really new to regular expressions. I have managed to match the HTML files in the current directory with this regexpr `^.+\.html$`.
I need to descend to the directory tree to access `./css/anyfile.css` files.

I've tried this: `^(.+\.html)|(css/.+\.css)$`. I am checking the regular expression with `ls | egrep 'regexpr'`, running it at project root.
I only get as result the `.html` file.

It seems weird that it doesn't work, because [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload#guardfile) using this block:

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  # Rails Assets Pipeline
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end
```

it can acess subdirectories such as `app`,`public` and `config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slash, so your regexp becomes `^(.+\.html)|(css\/.+\.css)$`. You can use http://rubular.com to check if the RegExp is a valid Ruby Regexp.